# How can I organize my code more in order to prevent the undesired behavior?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, debugging

As of now, I've written a script for a timer to countdown to a specific day.  The problem is that the moment you refresh the browser, it takes 1 second for it to appear as opposed to it appearing instantly.

I actually did figure out a way to make it appear instantly but I had to repeat the block of code with `countDownDate, now, timeDifference, oneDay, days, hours, minutes, seconds` and `document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = ...;` by placing it directly on top of `timer()` which's totally inefficient.

In my attempt below, the countdown appears about one second upon the browser refreshing but I want it to appear instantly.  My goal here is to create reusable code.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's the html:

```
<h1 id="timer"></h1>
```

Here's the js:

```
function conversion() {
    var countDownDate = new Date("June 1, 2019 24:00:00");

    var now = new Date().getTime(); 
    var timeDifference = countDownDate - now; 
    var oneDay         = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; 

    var days = Math.floor(timeDifference / (oneDay));
    var hours = Math.floor((timeDifference % (oneDay)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((timeDifference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((timeDifference % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
}

function timerCountdown() {
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        conversion();
        if(timeDifference < 0) { 
            clearInterval(timer); 
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Timer's over."; 
        } 

    }, 1000); 
}

timerCountdown();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `setInterval` callback into a variable, and *both* call `setInterval` with that function *and* call it immediately on pageload:

```
function timerCountdown() {
  var timer = setInterval(intervalCb, 1000); 
  function intervalCb() {
    conversion();
    if(timeDifference < 0) { 
      clearInterval(timer); 
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Timer's over."; 
    }
  }
  intervalCb();
}
timerCountdown();
```

Comment: Hey, this answer makes sense thank you, I finally understand it.  But there's one thing I tried on my end which raised a question.  I removed `var timer = ` and only left `setInterval(intervalCb, 1000);`, I placed the `if(timeDifference < 0) {...}` inside `conversion()` and the program ran just fine.  What would be the reason for this?  Seems like strange behavior since  `timer` in `clearInterval(timer);` isn't inside the scope in `conversion()`.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, did you test it in a situation where the interval was expected to be cleared? Without a persistent `timer` variable in scope, `clearInterval(timer)` will throw a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: You might just define `conversion` inside `timerCountdown`, just like `intervalCb` is also defined inside `timerCountdown`, that way `timeDifference` is in scope of both `timerCoutndown` and `conversion` without being global.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed I could do that too.  I also came up with some other ways.  Thanks again :D.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `conversion()` immeadiately.